# Hiding navbar component from login page is not working

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular.

On the login page Navbar should not be shown, once the login is successful it should be visible. I think I have some logic problem here so  I'm going to point out my issue by code:

here is my app.component

```
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" *ngIf="toShow">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/app-dashboard">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/app-events">EventLog</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/app-turbine-comparison">TurbineComparison</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>


         <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

an my app.componenent.ts i have :

```
        token: string;
    toShow:boolean=false;

    ngOnInit(){
      if(localStorage.getItem('token').length>0){
      this.toShow=true;
      }
    }


    Logout(){
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      this.toShow=false;
    }
```

When I am on my login page the navbar is visible. When I am logged in it is hidden. Can you please tell me where im doing wrong? Is it the right approach to put this logic and navbar in `app.component.ts`?

Comment: Do your navbar should be visible only when you're loggedin ?

Comment: @Emilien yes when a user  logs in  should be able to see Navbar

Comment: And what if you console.log `localStorage.getItem('token').length` in ngOnInit ?

Comment: @Emilien i think thats also an issue, because if im not logged i see an error "cant get the length of undefied" and when im logged in its bigger than zero

Comment: Could you test with `if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {...}`

Comment: @Emilien  i could log  in but the navbar is not visible

Answer (score 2):

Try this and add more component like `home-component`:

In `app-component` only add your `router-outlet` and add `nav-bar` in `home-component`

like this:

**app.component:**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**home-component:**

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/app-dashboard">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/app-events">EventLog</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/app-turbine-comparison">TurbineComparison</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In `home-component` you have any other `router-outlet` to load other components after logins on the home page.

To handle this structure you should have this router config:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: LoginComponent // this is the component with the <router-outlet> in the app-component
  },
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, // this is the component with the <router-outlet> in the app-component
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child-a', // this is the component with the <router-outlet> in the home-component
        component: ChildAComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'child-b',
        component: ChildBComponent, // this is the component with the <router-outlet> in the home-component
      },
    ],
  }
];
```

**Note**: This above structure recommended structure for handle your requirement and although is best practice.

**More info**: In this structure, you have an empty login page without any menu items in an empty router path. and after login, you redirected to the home page with menu items and load another component in the inner outlet with a click on the menu items.

**This link helps you get more info**: [Angular router](https://angular.io/guide/router)